# How to extract the numeric part of a string in sqlite python

Tags: python, sqlite

I am working on the IMDB dataset and I have the records of my movie table as follows

```
import sqlite3
import pandas as pd
conn=sqlite3.connect('Db-IMDB.db')
result1=pd.read_sql_query('select year from Movie order by year',conn)
print(type(result1))
print(result1)
```

I get the output as shown below

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
           year
0          1931
1          1936
2          1936
3          1936
4          1939
...         ...
3470    IV 2011
3471    IV 2017
3472     V 2015
3473    VI 2015
3474  XVII 2016

[3475 rows x 1 columns]
```

The data type of the year column is text.

So can I know how to get only the numeric part of the data so that I can do numeric operations like % so that I can get leap years in sqlite?

Answer (score 0):

Use regex:

```
def findNum(x):
    return re.findall(r'[0-9]+',x)[0]


df = pd.DataFrame({
    'a':['IV 2014','2015','v 2016']
    })

#float just for typecasting so that use can do numeric operations
print(df['a'].apply(findNum).apply(float))
```

Output:

```
0    2014
1    2015
2    2016
Name: a, dtype: float64
[Finished in 2.4s]
```

Answer (score 0):

If the non-numerics are Roman numerals and spaces to the left of the numerical component, as suggested by the example, then you could use SQLite's `ltrim` function:

```
sqlite> select ltrim("XVI   1955", "CDILMVX ");
1955
```

You might want to consider a more comprehensive list of characters to discard, e.g.

```
"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz_ "
```